# Questions about day settings when setting alarms in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I created a SchedulePicker using the **optionset**

After that, I also created a function that converts the **number of days from 0 to 127** into string.

```
struct WeekDay {
  let rawValue: Int
  let name: String

  static let mon = WeekDay(rawValue: 1, name: "Monday")
  static let tue = WeekDay(rawValue: 1<<1, name: "Tuesday")
  static let wed = WeekDay(rawValue: 1<<2, name: "Wednesday")
  static let thu = WeekDay(rawValue: 1<<3, name: "Thursday")
  static let fri = WeekDay(rawValue: 1<<4, name: "Friday")
  static let sat = WeekDay(rawValue: 1<<5, name: "Saturday")
  static let sun = WeekDay(rawValue: 1<<6, name: "Sunday")

  static let all: [WeekDay] = [.mon, .tue, .wed, .thu, .fri, .sat, .sun]
  func isIncluded(in schedule: Int) -> Bool {
    return schedule & rawValue == rawValue
  }
}

fileprivate func convertSchedule(_ schedule: Int) -> String {
  var daysToRepeat = WeekDay.all.filter({ $0.isIncluded(in: schedule) })

  if daysToRepeat.count == 0 {
    return "none"
  } else if daysToRepeat.count == 1 {
    return "Every \(daysToRepeat[0].name)"
  } else {
    return daysToRepeat.map({ $0.name }).joined(separator: ",")
  }
}
```

Now all I need is to create a `weekday` for `DateComponents ()`

weekday consists of 1 = Sunday to 7 = Saturday.

How can I map 128 **SchedulePicker** cases and **weekday** in `DateComponents()` ?

Comment: Unclear what the question is. If you know the date you know the weekday, so what’s the problem? Please rephrase, or give sample input and output, preferably both.

Comment: The point of my question is how to replace a known ```schedule date(0~127)``` with ```DateComponents()```  ```Weekday```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering whether problem isn't the initial choice of representation. I'd do something like this:

```
enum Weekday : Int, CaseIterable {
    case mon = 1
    case tue
    case wed
    case thu
    case fri
    case sat
    case sun
    var name : String {
        let greg = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let dayNames = greg.weekdaySymbols
        return dayNames[self.rawValue]
    }
}
```

That makes manipulating the info very easy:

```
let weekdaysChosen : [Weekday] = [.mon, .tue, .fri] // example
let namesOfWeekdays = weekdaysChosen.map{$0.name}.joined(separator: ", ")
print(namesOfWeekdays) // "Mon, Tue, Fri"
let numbersOfWeekdays = weekdaysChosen.map{$0.rawValue}
print(numbersOfWeekdays) // [1, 2, 5]
```